# Live calculation inside a reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple multiplication inside a reactive form:

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Menge</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="unit_amount" (input)="calculateWorth()" matInput required />
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Stückpreis (EUR)</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="unit_price" (input)="calculateWorth()" matInput />
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Wert (EUR)</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="unit_worth" [(ngModel)]="calculatedWorth" matInput />
</mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
calculateWorth(): void {
    if (this.formGroup.get('unit_price').value === null && this.formGroup.get('unit_amount').value === null) {
      this.calculatedWorth = 0.00;
    } else if (this.formGroup.get('unit_price').value === null) {
      this.calculatedWorth = 0.00;
    } else if (this.formGroup.get('unit_amount').value === null) {
      this.calculatedWorth = 0.00;
    } else {
      this.calculatedWorth = +(this.formGroup.get('unit_price').value.replace(',', '.')) * +(this.formGroup.get('unit_amount').value.replace(',', '.'));
    }
  }
```

I have a similar approach on my add-function, where this works, but when I edit a given row, the value of "calculatedWorth" only is changed when I change both factors. Btw. this line:

```
[(ngModel)]="calculatedWorth"
```

seems to be deprecated since NG6, is there a better way to render the value inside an disabled inputfield?

Thx and regards.

Edit: When I change the (input)-Binding to (change)-Binding in HTML, the calculation works live, after I changed both factors once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ngModel. NgModel and reactive forms cannot be used together.

Update unit_worth in the form group like this in each of your conditions.

```
this.formGroup.patchValue({
  unit_worth: 0 (or your calculated value)
})
```

Do not disable the field. Set the field to read only on the input.

Comment: Thx, this works - deprecation warning has gone away. I also had to remove the str.replace-func, after that the live-calc works from the beginning.